# How to calculate the total sum of a column inside a listview?

Tags: vb.net

How do I sum up the total prices in a listview column in VB.Net on a click of a button, and then display it inside a textbox?

Comment: Iterate through each item in the list view, extract the price if necessary, add up the price, and set the textbox to that total.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. A `ListView` is meant for display, not for storing data. Your button should use data source the listview is using, to compute the value of the textbox.

Comment: Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: Use a DataGridView instead of a ListView.

Comment: @Plutonix I would say my question is good according to what I have read.

Comment: @rheitzman Would be a good idea I suppose